# rspec way for passing variable between multiple contexts

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I was wondering what would be the best way to pass variable between multiple contexts (or multiple its) in rspec but without using global variables?

For example, I have this:

```
describe "My test" do
    let(:myvar) { @myvar = 0 }

    context "First test pass" do
        it "passes" do
            myvar = 20
            expect(myvar).to eq(20)
        end
    end

    context "Second test pass" do
        it "passes" do
            expect(myvar).to eq(20)
        end
    end
end
```

Now, obviously, this will not work with let because with new context, myvar variable will be back on initial state which is = 0.
I would need mechanism to "cache state" between two contexts which would in turn give me value of myvar = 20 in second context

Any opinions, suggestions and improvements are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Simply not passing variable between contexts is better. If you need a context, create it in the context block.

Answer (score 8):

Another simple way, would be to define a 'local variable' in describe context.
the 'local variable' would live throughout the describe, and any changes during run time would effect it, and so change it.

For example

```
describe 'tests' do
    context 'Sharing a variable across tests' do
        var = 1
        puts var

        it "it one. var = #{var}" do
            var = var*2
            puts var
        end
        it "it two" do
            puts var
        end
    end
end
```

**Output**

```
1
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

1. What happens is not what you think happens.
2. What you want to happen break "unit testing" as a methodology.

Let me explain #2 first - unit testing test cases should be able to work *in isolation*, which means that they should work when run together, when run apart, and in any order... so much so that some unit testing frameworks (like the default one in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir)) run test cases in *parallel*...

As for #1 - when you write `myvar = 20` you are not assigning a value to `let(:myvar) { @myvar = 0 }`, you simply create a *local variable*, which will override all calls to `myvar` within the method, but will not be available *outside* the method (`myvar` will return `0`).

Even if you would have set `@myvar = 20` (unless you do it *before* you call `myvar` for the first time) instead, `myvar` would still return `0`, since the `let` function is using a *memento* pattern, which means it is called once, and subsequent calls return the value originally returned (in this case `0`):

```
puts myvar
@myvar = 20
puts myvar

# => 0
# => 0
```

Comment: So in nutshell, let gives us possibility to define starting state (whether it is object or simple type) which can be used through subsequent contexts but not altered?

Comment: @BakirJusufbegovic - no, it is re-created for each test case, but not _within_ a test case (more than once)

Comment: This means let is re-created between examples (it's) but not within a same example (when used multiple times). Guess let cannot be used for mechanism that I need and it is ability to "cache state" of some variable between examples. I understand that unit testing should not work in that way (tests should be independent) but I'm using RSpec for functional tests where these examples (or I would rather call them test steps) execute in sequential order and often output of some example will be needed as input to next one

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. How I solved it was by using factory_girl gem.

Here's the basics:

create a factory:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'faker' # you can use faker, if you want to use the factory to generate fake data

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :generate_data, class: MyModule::MyClass do
    key 100 # doesn't matter what you put here, it's just a placeholder for now
    another_key 'value pair'
  end
end
```

Now after you made the factory you need to make a Model that looks like this:

```
Module MyModule
  class MyClass
    #for every key you create in your factory you must have a corresponding attribute accessor in the model.
    attr_accessor :key, :another_key

    #you can also place methods here to call from your spec test, if you wish
    # def self.test
        #some test
    # end
  end
end
```

Now going back to your example you can do something like this:

```
describe "My test" do
    let(:myvar) { @myvar }

    context "First test pass" do
        it "passes" do
            @myvar.key = 20 #when you do this you set it now from 100 to 20
            expect(@myvar.key).to eq(20)
        end
    end

    context "Second test pass" do
        it "passes" do
            expect(@myvar.key).to eq(20) #it should still be 20 unless you overwrite that variable
        end
    end
end
```

As stated by others, not proper way of unit testing. But, how should we know if you're unit testing or not. So, I won't judge.
Anyways, good luck let us know, if you got some other solution!